# WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

Hy,I work with faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8 pretrained model. I have problems when evaluating the model. The training went without any problems. I start the evaluation of the model with the command:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=./training_outlook_action_ctx/training_1/pipeline.config --model_dir=./training_outlook_action_ctx/training_1 --checkpoint_dir=./training_outlook_action_ctx/training_1
```

After the first Loaded cuDNN version 8400, it starts throwing me the following error that repeats itself until it interrupts

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
W0810 10:17:12.131517 140545620840832 coco_evaluation.py:113] Ignoring ground truth with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
W0810 10:17:12.131881 140545620840832 coco_evaluation.py:196] Ignoring detection with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
W0810 10:17:12.652873 140545620840832 coco_evaluation.py:113] Ignoring ground truth with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring detection with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
W0810 10:17:12.653055 140545620840832 coco_evaluation.py:196] Ignoring detection with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
WARNING:tensorflow:Ignoring ground truth with image id 1016176252 since it was previously added
```

here is my pipeline.config file

```
# Faster R-CNN with Resnet-50 (v1)
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint

# This config is TPU compatible.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 7
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        width: 1024
        height: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101_keras'
      batch_norm_trainable: true
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        share_box_across_classes: true
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    use_static_shapes: true
    use_matmul_crop_and_resize: true
    clip_anchors_to_image: true
    use_static_balanced_label_sampler: true
    use_matmul_gather_in_matcher: true
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 2
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 200000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 100000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/pretrained_models/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_1024x1024_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
     random_square_crop_by_scale {
      scale_min: 0.6
      scale_max: 1.3
    }
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  use_bfloat16: true  # works only on TPUs
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "./training_outlook_action_ctx/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./training_outlook_action_ctx/data/train.records"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 2
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "./training_outlook_action_ctx/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./training_outlook_action_ctx/data/train.records"
  }
}
```

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Python: 3.9.12

Tensorflow: 2.9.1

I tried to add `num_examples` and `max_evals` but failed. No matter how I adjust them, it still throws the same error

I must mention that the evaluation on the second dataset worked normally for me

**Thanks in advance**
Edi

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys. I found a solution for how I used the script to create images and annotations. More precisely, I used a script that will crop my first-level annotations and create new XML files for cropped images. The filename and path were not good for me in the XML files (wrong path when programming the script).

After the change, the evaluation code error disappeared.

For all the questions I am available.